# Never use a specific sink in PulseAudio

Tags: pulseaudio

I listen to music trough my bluetooth headphones. When I connect my laptop to a hub (display, aux, internet, ...), pulseaudio switches to the new sink because module-switch-on-connect is activated. But I never use the audio through that usb cable. Is there a way to let pulseaudio ignore this sink? I want to keep module-switch-on-connect, because it works nicely switching from bluetooth to laptop speakers etc.

Comment: Exactly my question. But maybe better at SuperUser?

Answer (score 1):

With upcoming PulseAudio 14.0, maybe we have a solution with `module-switch-on-connect blacklist=<regex>` parameter.

```
leho@papaya $ pactl describe-module module-switch-on-connect
Name: module-switch-on-connect
Version: 13.99.1
Description: When a sink/source is added, switch to it or conditionally switch to it
Author: Michael Terry
Usage: only_from_unavailable=<boolean, only switch from unavailable ports> ignore_virtual=<boolean, ignore new virtual sinks and sources, defaults to true> blacklist=<regex, ignore matching devices> 
Load Once: yes
```

Source: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Notes/14.0/

Comment: You have to use `pacmd describe-module` though, `pactl` doesn't provide that subcommand.